# Make round edged button in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to make my button round edged. My button code is as follows:-

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  BorderThickness="1" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" Width="85"  Background="#6F933D" BorderBrush="#48671E" CommandParameter="11" Command="{Binding AuditCommand}" Visibility="{Binding ViewModel.IsCompleteAccessible}" Margin="38,0,60,0" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Complete</Button>
```

Please Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="test" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="ButtonBorder" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightGray">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" Style="{StaticResource test}" Margin="0,137,0,0"  />
<Grid>
```